# selectively format values in an array

Tags: php

Given data in an array, I'd like to format the number values so 2 decimal places and the digit separator are displayed.  Here is an example:

```
$array = [
'accountID' => 1000,
'scenarioID' => 2,
'income' => 34560.78,
'expenses' => 1500,
'comments' => 'abc'
];

$formatted_array = array_map(
 function($value) { return is_numeric($value) ? number_format($value, 2) : $value; },
 $array);

echo '<pre>' . print_r($formatted_array, 1) . '</pre>';
```

And here is the result of the above code:
[image]

However, key/value pairs in the array that are IDs should not display the decimal places or digit separator - they need to be excluded from the number formatting.  To address this, I have tried replacing `$formatted_array` as follows:

```
$formatted_array = array_walk(
$array, function(&$value, $key) { return (is_numeric($value) and !in_array($key, ['accountID', 'scenarioID'])) ? number_format($value, 2) : $value; });
```

but nothing is returned at all and there is no error message.  What needs to be modified in the `array_walk` version so it works as desired?

Comment: [`array_walk`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) returns a boolean result, and passes the `$array` by-reference instead, changing the values directly at `$array`. Replace `return` with `$value =`. Or use `array_map( "callback", array_keys($array), $array);`

Comment: Replacing `return` with `$value =`, as you recommended, solved it!  Much obliged.

Comment: just like @fyrye said, no need to reassign since `array_walk` actually returns boolean, just follow the examples in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Comment: Again `$formatted_array` will be boolean. You need to do https://3v4l.org/TWDlQ or https://3v4l.org/PrZ1H

Comment: @fyrye For the `array_map` solution that you provided here https://3v4l.org/PrZ1H, is there a way to retain the key descriptions (ie. accountID, scenarioID, income, expenses, comments)?

Comment: One approach would be to wrap it with `array_column(array_map('callback', array_keys($array), $array),1, 0)` and return an array of key and values `return [$key, $value]`. https://3v4l.org/nMJFI One note on the ternary operator though, to avoid unexpected results, the parentheses should wrap your condition and results. For example `(true ? 'yes' : 'no')` This way you don't run into issues with `(true) ? 'yes' : (false) ? 'no' : 'nothing'`  https://3v4l.org/bDXu7